# Is there a way to keep the result of a pipe inside a template input variable in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I really like the syntax of the `*ngFor` directive.
You can iterate over all the elements of an array.

I would like to achieve the same thing with the result of a pipe. For example the `async` pipe.
When placing the `async` pipe everywhere inside my template where I use a property of the result of an observable, I have a lot of subscriptions going on and my template is cluttered with something like `{{(someObservable$ | async)?.propertyName}}`.
Is there a way to simply bind the current result of the pipe to a template input variable like this?

```
<div let="currentValue = someObservable$ | async">
  {{currentValue?.foo}}, {{currentValue?.bar}}
  ...
</div>
```

I tried this in combination with `*ngIf`, but this does not seem to be a valid template expression:

```
<div *ngIf="let currentValue = someObservable$ | async">
  {{currentValue?.foo}}, {{currentValue?.bar}}
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Looking for solutions for precisely the same issue.. hope it will be possible in the future..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! As of angular 4+, we can store result of **successful `*ngIf`**, like:

```
<div *ngIf="userObservable | async; else loading; let user">
  Hello {{user.last}}, {{user.first}}!
</div>
<template #loading>Waiting...</template>
```

> If you need same with `*ngFor`, simply wrap it in `*ngIf` ;-)

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13297)

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue to support that https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2451

Currently it's very limited what can be assigned to a template variable.

- a reference to the element or component of the tag where it is added
- `exportAs` like `<form #f="ngForm">`
- `let i=index` in `ngFor` and similar predefined variables in other directives

As workaround you can execute the expression in a method in the component class and make the result available in a property the view can bind to.

Too much logic in the template is discouraged anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
My concerns with the Workaround is performance (see http://briantroncone.com/?p=623) and the fact that I always have to implement the `OnDestroy` interface to unsubscribe from the observable again.