# Context of pipe "As" object

Tags: angular

I read about the "as" syntax you can use for a pipe in Angular 4

I was hoping I would be able to have it assigned to a variable in my component but it seems to be in its own context.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | p1:arg | .. | pN:arg as filteredResults>
  {{filteredResults.length}} <!-- correct here -->
</div>

{{filteredResults.length}} <!-- incorrect here -->
```

I have a setter for my object and it never gets called, which is probably correct, but is there a way to accomplish this?

```
set filteredResults(items: Item[]) {
    debugger;
    this._filteredResults = items;

}
```

I was thinking I could have a service to communicate between the last pipe in the chain and the paging control but that seems disgustingly hacky and I really don't want to do that.

Comment: You want to use the `filteredResults` property to receive the output of a pipe?

Comment: Yes,  in the end I have the classic paging control,
<< | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | >> 
sort of thing,and i want the buttons to reflect the output of the pipe, rather than the base array..  this is how I was attempting to do it.

Comment: Similar goal to this question, though there was no answer there either.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057352/angular-4-store-pipe-output-variable-for-use-outside-of-template

Comment: `filteredResults` is block-scoping aka not visible outside the div, it's a `let` declaration like.
Any reasons why you don't inject the pipes in your component, do the pipe chaining, save the result in a variable that you use in the view ?

Comment: I guess I'm not familiar with what you mean by injecting the pipes, do you have an example you can share?